# Update Query Doesnt work?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

These are my table structures

**tblcomment**
    - - - - - - - - - - - - -
comment_id
content_id
user_id
picture_id
comment
comment_time

**tblpictures**
    - - - - - - - - - - - - -
content_id
title
picture_id

I am trying to update the content_id field on pictures  using this but it doesnt seem to work ?

```
UPDATE `comments`
SET 
comments.content_id = pictures.content_id
WHERE
comments.picture_id = pictures.picture_id
```

I get this error

`1054 - Unknown column 'pictures.picture_id' in 'where clause'`

Comment: I fixed it for this one, but please use the `code` button to format your posts correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UPDATE comments, pictures SET ...`